# Titanium App fails to launch with ti.main.js file not found error

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

App fails to launch on iOS and hangs on the splash screen. No error messages on AppC side but when I run the app on Xcode I get the "Could not find the file ti.main.js" error.

environement:

Node.js Version             = 8.9.1

npm Version                 = 5.5.1

CLI Version                 = 5.1.1

Stack trace from Xcode:

```
2019-03-08 21:24:21.292325-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365500] [DEBUG] Reading stylesheet from: /Users/kamrezvani/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B115B8C1-3E00-4897-B2F5-FA830C10F5BD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/463090AA-E8E0-4110-9798-0C65E6BCB7E0/TrafficTix.app/stylesheet.plist
2019-03-08 21:24:21.372005-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365500] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "fetch" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2019-03-08 21:24:21.372127-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365500] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2019-03-08 21:24:21.516987-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365762] [DEBUG] Loading: /Users/kamrezvani/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B115B8C1-3E00-4897-B2F5-FA830C10F5BD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/463090AA-E8E0-4110-9798-0C65E6BCB7E0/TrafficTix.app/ti.main.js, Resource: ti_main_js
2019-03-08 21:24:21.520121-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365762] [ERROR] Error loading path: file:///Users/kamrezvani/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B115B8C1-3E00-4897-B2F5-FA830C10F5BD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/463090AA-E8E0-4110-9798-0C65E6BCB7E0/TrafficTix.app/ti.main.js, Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “ti.main.js” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/kamrezvani/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B115B8C1-3E00-4897-B2F5-FA830C10F5BD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/463090AA-E8E0-4110-9798-0C65E6BCB7E0/TrafficTix.app/ti.main.js, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003342e50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
2019-03-08 21:24:21.520393-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365762] [ERROR] Script Error Could not find the file ti.main.js
2019-03-08 21:24:21.542421-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365762] [DEBUG] Application booted in 169.842958 ms
2019-03-08 22:18:54.187795-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365500] [DEBUG] Loading: /Users/kamrezvani/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B115B8C1-3E00-4897-B2F5-FA830C10F5BD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/463090AA-E8E0-4110-9798-0C65E6BCB7E0/TrafficTix.app/_app_props_.json, Resource: _app_props__json
2019-03-08 22:18:54.187943-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365500] [ERROR] Could not load tiapp.xml properties, error was File not found
2019-03-08 22:18:54.644674-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365500] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/kamrezvani/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B115B8C1-3E00-4897-B2F5-FA830C10F5BD/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-03-08 22:18:54.646402-0800 TrafficTix[93730:2365500] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

When I run it through Terminal, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Error: invalid session
    at _makeError (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/auth.js:427:14)
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/auth.js:270:21
    at Request._callback (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/index.js:135:11)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
---------------------------------------------
    at Request.init (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/request/request.js:188:10)
    at new Request (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/request/request.js:127:8)
    at request (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/request/index.js:53:10)
    at Function.get (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/request/index.js:61:12)
    at _createRequest (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/index.js:239:39)
    at Object.Appc.createRequest (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/index.js:101:9)
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/auth.js:265:8
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3888:9
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
---------------------------------------------
    at post (/Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.1.GA/iphone/cli/hooks/run.js:111:6)
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:235:13
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3845:9
    at replenish (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1030:17)
    at iterateeCallback (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1015:17)
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:988:16
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3850:13
    at apply (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:41:25)
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:76:12
---------------------------------------------
    at Domain.<anonymous> (/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/plugins/com.appcelerator.titanium.liveview.core_1.1.0.1505720032/node_modules/liveview/hook/lvhook.js:181:6)
    at Domain.run (domain.js:242:14)
    at /Applications/Appcelerator Studio/plugins/com.appcelerator.titanium.liveview.core_1.1.0.1505720032/node_modules/liveview/hook/lvhook.js:176:10
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:235:13
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3845:9
    at replenish (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1030:17)
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1034:9
    at eachOfLimit (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1061:22)
    at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/7.0.9/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1066:16
```

Comment: try disabling liveview and try again? Errors aren't always there or correct when using liveview

Comment: Did you fix it, I'm getting the same error, can you or someone help me out
?